# Include Nested Tables in LINQ Method syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, extension-methods

I have 4 tables connected with foreign keys.

`MasterTable01` (Foreign Key `MasterTable02Id`)

`MasterTable02` (Foreign Key `MasterTable03Id`)

`MasterTable03` (Foreign Key `MasterTable04Id`)

`MasterTable04`

Now I want to include all these tables in my result set.

```
var result = context.MasterTable01
                    .Include(MasterTable01)
                    .Include(MasterTable02.MasterTable03)
                    .Include(MasterTable03.MasterTable04)
```

And how to read nested values.

```
result.foreach(x => new myObject(x.MasterTable01.Desc,
                                 x.MasterTable01.MasterTable02.Desc,
                                 x.MasterTable01.MasterTable02.MasterTable03.Desc));
```

Comment: This code will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

If the tables are 1 to many then:

```
var result=context.MasterTable01
  .Include(t1=>t1.MasterTable02.Select(t2=>t2.MasterTable03.Select(t3=>t3.MasterTable04))
```

If the tables are 1:1 then:

```
var result=context.MasterTable01
  .Include(t1=>t1.MasterTable02.MasterTable03.MasterTable04)
```